# Use XML Encryption to encrypt JSON data

Tags: xml, json, security, encryption

I have developed an application that creates JSON objects, sending them to other devices  through Bluetooth. I have already applied several encryption algorithms like AES, 3DES or Blowfish, encrypting the JSON objects, but now i was asked to try a different approach by using XML Encryption to encrypt the JSON objects I must sent over the network.

**Question 1:** Does it make sense to use XML Encryption on top of the JSON objects?

Moreover, i have researched a lot about XML Encryption, but all of them concerned **XML documents** encryption exclusively, although some sources mentioned that it is possible to apply XML encryption to non-xml documents, but none of them had examples of how to do it.

**Question 2:** Is it really possible to encrypt, let's say a JSON object, with XML Encryption?

Can anyone point me any information about how to encrypt any data other than XML documentos?
I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Yes, it's possible to encrypt non-XML data but he method depends on the used library. Our SecureBlackbox supports this, but it might be too big for your task.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll have a check on SecureBlackBox, and I'll let you know if it fits my needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of why you are being asked to use XML encryption, I am forced to speculate, although I would be curious as to why it is necessary given that you've already encrypted your data to the hilt with fantastic algorithms.

Are you exposing sensitive information in plain text?  If so, encrypt it with the algoritms you mentioned.  Are you worried about aggregation?  If so, encrypt everything including names and values.  Under most of the situations I can think of, you wouldn't need to add XML encrytion on top of what you already have.  It sounds like overkill to me, though as a paranoid type I can appreciate that :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! The reason I was told to perform data encryption with XML Encryption was simply to be able to have something so I can compare the performance with the traditional algorithms i've mentioned (AES,3DES,...), I do not desire to do double encryption. Knowing that, do you think that is not redundant, since I have my data in JSON, and I'll encrypt it using XML Encryption? Do you know where I can find an example where XML Encryotion is used to encrypt non-XML data? Thanks for your attention!

Comment: @Fabio actually, XML encryption is the same AES/DES/... encoded to base64 and wrapped into XML. So it would be slower than "raw" AES encryption.

Comment: Thanks for you response,that was a great help.You're right, you just made me realize I would still use the very same algorithms I've used before.So I guess i better forget this XML Encryption approach, and start thinking in alternatives,maybe JSON Web Algorithms but there is not much information about it mainly because it's still very recent.I guess i'll have to spend quite a few time trying to understand how JSON security standards work and if that would fit my needs or if it's possible to apply it in my case.I really need to compare the traditional algorithms with some new different approach